# Having dynamic content while keeping old static page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of videos title. Each goes to a page with the video in question and some information (player, description, discussion, ...).

```
<div id="video-list">
<a href="/Video/title-1">Title 1</a><br />
<a href="/Video/title-2">Title 2</a><br />
<a href="/Video/title-3">Title 3</a><br />
</div>
```

I want to make things a little more dynamic with Javascript/JQuery. Screen split in two, video list on the left and information on the right.

```
<a href="javascript: PlayVideo(123);">Title 1</a>
```

But I still want to keep the old link for people without javascript and for search engine crawler.

Is this a good idea to have something like

```
<a href="/Video/title-1" videoid="123">Title 1</a>
```

and use JQuery to loop all anchor to get the videoid and replace the href?

(server side is asp.net mvc, the javascript and static side already work)

Answer (score 0):

you can use framesets, works with every browser. its a old way but will give u what u want as it doesnt depends on Javascript

```
<frameset cols="25%,*">
  <frame src="frame_a.htm">
  <frame src="frame_b.htm">
</frameset>
```

for your reference [frameset](http://www.quackit.com/html/templates/frames/frames_example_1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can use iFrame to achieve what you want. Split the screen into two div, left div store the links, right div store iframe and video player.

http://jsfiddle.net/2vmYG/ -> full css

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="videoList">
        <a href='http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xzvsp7_joe-jack-the-mogul-mulla_music#.UZMPerUwpuA' target="video">Video 1</a><br/>
        <a href='http://www.dailymotion.com/video/xzu16h_daft-punk-random-access-memories-unboxed_music#.UZMPRbUwpuA' target="video">Video 2</a><br/>
    </div>
    <div id="videoPlayer">
        <iframe id='video' src=""></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you are looking for a full AJAX/jQuery solution, you will need a player (flowplayer, jwplayer) etc.